# How to have webpack avoid rebuilding all entries on watch when a file is modified?

Tags: webpack, sass

I know this question was asked many times, but I'm not sure there is no recent evolution on this.

webpack is used as an assets compiler for SASS/SCSS, less and stylus. The project use all these 3 style languages.
There is a performance issue because it compile foundation (sites framework) with take tens of seconds.

After switched to `sass-embedded`, the compile time greatly improved. But still take ≈12 seconds.

The major problem is during development, I rely of livereload to "instantly" see modifications but since it take so much time, it is unusable.

We do not change .scss files so often, and the project use stylus on most parts. So basically we didn't require webpack to recompile all foundation each time a stylus file is changed.

There is a way to indicate webpack to smartly build entries according to rules involved ?

Here the `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin = require('webpack-remove-empty-scripts');
const LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  devtool: "source-map", // any "source-map"-like devtool is possible
  plugins: [
    new LiveReloadPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new RemoveEmptyScriptsPlugin(),
  ],
  entry: {
    "stylus_css/project": "/app/stylus/project.styl",
    "sass_css/project": "/app/sass/project.scss",
    "less_css/project": "/app/less/project.less",
  },
  output: {
    path: "/app/",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // Compile Stylus to CSS
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "stylus-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },

      // Compile SASS to CSS
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },

      // Compile LESS to CSS
      {
        test: /\.less$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },

    ],
  },
};
```

package.json:

```json
{
    ...,
    "dependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
        "less": "^4.1.3",
        "less-loader": "^11.0.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
        "sass-embedded": "^1.63.6",
        "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
        "stylus": "^0.59.0",
        "stylus-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
        "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "webpack-remove-empty-scripts": "^1.0.1"
    }
}
```